# Hierarchical Data to arrayList using recursion. (Java)

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I have hierarchical data in MySQL of employees and their subordinates as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U12WJ.png) There is a joining column 'managerID' which references to the employee ID in the same column.

My objective is to recursively go through this data and add it all to an arrayList which would end up looking like this:

```
[Tom [Hanna [George [Chris], Rachel]]]
```

But there is a logic problem in my java function:

```
public void getList(String employeeName, ArrayList<Object> arrayList) {

    // Initialise the arrayList the first time
    if (arrayList == null) {
        arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // Using the string provided, I have found the employee
    Employee employee = employeeRepository.findByName(employeeName);

    // adding employee to the list
    arrayList.add(employee);

    // Getting list of employee's subordinates
    List<Employee> subordinates = employee.getSubordinates();

    // Checking if employee has subordinates
    if (subordinates != null) {

        // Iterate through each of their subordinates and call recursive  function
        for (int i = 0; i < subordinates.size(); i++) {
            ArrayList<Object> subOrdinateDetails = new ArrayList<>();

            // If the subordinate has subordinates, use recursion
            if (subordinates.get(i).getSubordinates() != null) {
                getList(subordinates.get(i).getName(), subordinatesDetails);
            }
            // Adding this list to the original arrayList
            arrayList.add(subOrdinateDetails);
        }
        System.out.println(arrayList.toString());
    }
}
```

The toString method at the end of the method does not print what I wanted above, instead it prints:

```
   [Chris]
   [George, [Chris]]
   [Rachel]
   [Hanna, [George, [Chris]], [Rachel]]
   [Tom, [Hanna, [George, [Chris]], [Rachel]]]
```

While trying to debug it, I tried to get the first index of the arrayList, to understand what it was here is what it printed:

```
 Chris
 George
 Rachel
 Hanna
 Tom
```

As you can tell, I am new to java, and I have failed debugging my code. If  you could point out my mistake, I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it like this.

```
public class Employee {
    private final String name;
    private final List<Employee> subordinates;

    public Employee(String name, List<Employee> subordinates) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.subordinates = subordinates;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public List<Employee> getSubordinates() {
        return subordinates;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(this.name);
        this.subordinates.forEach(emp -> {
            emp.print();
        });
    }

}

public class EmployeeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee chris = new Employee("chris", new ArrayList<>());
        Employee george = new Employee("george", Arrays.asList(chris));
        Employee rachell = new Employee("rachell", new ArrayList<>());
        Employee hannah = new Employee("hannan", Arrays.asList(george, rachell));
        Employee tom= new Employee("tom",Arrays.asList(hannah));

        tom.print();

    }

}
```

The trick in the recursion is each time it prints out the current employee, before printing any of it's subordinates as you can see in the method. I'll leave it to you to come up with the brackets if needed.